# Пробел в конце path при использовании os.path

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не понимаю, почему появляется пробел в конце:

```
import os
print(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('wsgi.py')))

/home/user/folder/app

print(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('wsgi.py'))),'/upload/')

/home/user/folder/app /upload/
```

и как этого избежать ?

Comment: Проблем или пробел в конце?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Скобка не там. У вас фактически `print` вызывается с параметрами

```
print('/home/user/folder/app', '/upload/')
```

Поэтому между выводимыми строками появляется пробел (`print` по умолчанию печатает свои параметры через пробел). Вместо этого оба параметра должны передаваться в `os.path.join()`.

У вас:

```
print(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('wsgi.py'))),'/upload/')
#                 (                                            )
```

А должно быть:

```
print(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('wsgi.py')),'/upload/'))
#                 (                                                       )
```

Ну и чтобы не запутаться в скобках и запятых лучше разбивать на отдельные этапы (расчет и вывод):

```
p = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('wsgi.py')),'/upload/')
print(p)
```

Также, можно использовать модуль [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), код получится более компактным и читаемым:

```
from pathlib import Path

print(Path('wsgi.py').resolve().parent / 'upload')
```

Answer (score 3):

Правильно расставлять скобки:

```
print(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('wsgi.py')),'upload'))
```