# синтаксис python: использование слэша /

Tags: python, синтаксис

Как понять вот это использование слэша и строки после присвоения здесь:

```
converted_path = assets / "converted"
```

И использование слэшей и строки здесь:

```
debug_log_path = converted_path / "debug" / datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
```

Как это называется?

Источник: https://github.com/SFTtech/openage/blob/2fa43ec433d6c4e094089aeb6b78dfd12bae3b8a/openage/convert/main.py#L59

Comment: Это обычный оператор деления. Но его действие перегружено для объектов типа Path из библиотеки pathlib (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). На входе в функцию передается переменная asset именно такого типа, поэтому все дальнейшие операции с таким объектом идут по его правилам

Comment: @Mike вот почему аннотация типов так полезна - чтобы не раскручивать такие цепочки.

Comment: Вообще не самый хороший код в примере. Как говорится в ZEN of Python - простое лучше сложного. Именно тот момент, когда для понимания строки кода придётся читать больше одной строки.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Ну это все же стандартная библиотека питона, причем базовая для работы с путями. И такое добавление пути через слэши выглядить довольно органично.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич код с использованием pathlib более простой и читаемый, чем код с использованием функций os.path. То что для понимания, как код работает внутри, еще нужно что-то почитать не перекрывает все преимущества pathlib.

Comment: Спасибо, код стал прозрачным.

Comment: @insolor не очевидное утверждение без аннотации типов :)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич аннотации типов - это вообще отдельный момент. У меня по умолчанию код плотно обложен аннотациями типов, как будто меня покусал джавист, так что никаких проблем с этим не испытываю. Еще один плюс pathlib - IDE сразу подсказывает, что с объектом можно сделать, какие методы у него есть, а для os.path постоянно приходится гуглить документацию даже для самых простых операций.

Comment: @insolor ну не знаю. Я наверное слишком много кода пишу под os.path, раз без всяких подсказок использую его наиболее популярные функции. От опрыта разработчика многое зависит. А вот с аннотациями и опыта надо меньше чутка.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич еще по поводу читаемости, вот для примера ответ, в конце вариант через pathlib намного более читаемый: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/687854/1365 Можно конечно по-другому импортировать, чтобы os.path постоянно не повторять, но все равно куча вложенных вызовов функций, куча скобок, в которых легко запутаться. Через patlib все просто пишется, слева направо, без вложенности, код как бы последовательно рассказывает историю.